# How to insert an image into MYSQL database using MIT app inventor 2 and php?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want some resources that will help me how to do this for job purposes because all I found was [this](http://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php) 
My plan is to use MIT app inventor 2 to do these steps.

> 1. Select an image from the photos gallery in the phone
> 2. Send it to a mySQL database row using app inventor blocks and php.
> 3. Retrieve the image from the database and display it in the app.

Comment: I don't know about that app but you should try to insert the url of the image into your table in the database instead of the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the image to a local folder to your app and then insert in the database the path to the image. Copying the image to your local storage will allow you to keep the image should the original be moved or deleted.

Comment: I'm not too sure how to do that